# Multiple definitions of 'Somefunction' , multiple definitions of DLLMain@12

Tags: c++

I'm writing a DLL to display `MessageBoxA` function from `user32.dll`.

I keep getting the errors

1. multiple definitions of 'SomeFunction'
2. multiple definition of 'DLLMain@12'
3. first defined here

Reading through some of the solutions and comparing the files that I have, `main.h` and `main.cpp` have a duplicate function `SomeFunction`. How do I correct this? The `ifndef` is defined in the header file `main.h`. I tried adding an inline syntax, but that didn't work.

`main.cpp`:

```
#include "main.h"

// a sample exported function
 void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext)
{
    MessageBoxA(0, sometext, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
}

extern "C" DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

`main.c`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <main.h>

void Test(void)

{
    MessageBoxA(
        NULL,
        "test",
        "",
        0);
}
```

`main.h`:

```
#ifndef __MAIN_H__
#define __MAIN_H__

#include <windows.h>

/*  To use this exported function of dll, include this header
 *  in your project.
 */

#ifdef BUILD_DLL
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

 void DLL_EXPORT SomeFunction(const LPCSTR sometext);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __MAIN_H__
```

Comment: You are doing something wrong, but it is hard to tell what.  Having both a main.cpp and a main.c file in a project is however certainly a bad idea.  They both get compiled to main.obj and overwrite each other's .obj file.  Last one wins, the linker errors are no joy.

Comment: I must have changed some file property or something, a file path maybe . It compiles now , which I don't understand why.....